# Uninstalling windows key from hdd

Tags: windows, windows-key

I'm frequently getting old hard drives that still have windows on it. Now I was thinking that I could get the windows license keys and use them to activate windows on another computer. I managed to get the key with some tool called ProtoKey and just tried to activate windows on another machine just to find out that you need to uninstall the key from the previous activation first (which makes a lot of sense lol). But that's not that easy because I get the hdds without the computer and  from what I know I can't just boot the windows on another computer. Does anybody know if I can somehow "uninstall" the keys?

Comment: This is a violation of the Windows end user license agreement. Windows licenses are not transferable from one machine to another except under specific circumstances, none of which apply here. Therefore this question is off-topic here.

Comment: If it is a Retail product key, then they are transferable.